# Organic reaction of dry ice and Grignard reagent

Tags: organic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds

> Which of the following product is formed in the reaction $\ce{CH3MgBr}$ in DryIce/acid?
>   **A**) $\ce{CH3COOH}$
>   **B**) $\ce{CH4}$
>   **C**) $\ce{CH3OH}$
>   **D**) $\ce{CH3CH2CHO}$

My answer is **A**, since dry ice is $\ce{CO2}$ and it has one carbon atom and reactant has one carbon, so in all the product should have two carbon atoms, which is option **A**.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are correct. Grignard reagents $\ce{RMgX}$ (where $\ce{R}$ stands for some hydrocarbon group and $\ce{X}$ is a halogen, usually $\ce{Cl}$, $\ce{Br}$, or $\ce{I}$) [react with carbon dioxide to produce carboxylic acids](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/351/Carey5th/Ch19/ch19-2-1.html) after acidic workup:

$$\ce{RMgX ->[1)\ \ce{ CO2}][2)\ \ce{ H3O+}] RCO2H}$$

$$\ce{RMgX + CO2 -> RCO2- MgX+}$$
$$\ce{RCO2- + H3O+ -> RCO2H + H2O}$$

> In general your reasoning when approaching this problem is a good one. If you are reacting two 1-carbon reagents, then you probably have a 2-carbon product.

Comment: Just to confirm, acidic workup or adding water, would be fine right?

Comment: Acidic workup would be better, since we want our *acidic* product and not its conjugate base.